# How do I get realtime audio from android

Tags: android, accessibility, audio-recording, real-time-data

I am trying to analyze internal audio from android system to know wave amplitude of the sound that is being played at the moment. I start playing the audio on the device and after more or less four seconds the apps gets the sound that was playing. I think that the problem could start with the priority of my app on the system that cannot get audio on real time or closer to it. 
I am using the `AudioRecord` from android

```
      internalRecorder = AudioRecord.Builder()
        .setAudioFormat(audioFormat)
        .setBufferSizeInBytes(124800)
        .setAudioPlaybackCaptureConfig(config)
        .build()
```

and the config:

```
val config = AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration.Builder(mediaProjection!!)
        .addMatchingUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
        .addMatchingUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_UNKNOWN)
        .addMatchingUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
        .build()
```

I have tried to make an accessibility service but this not improve the performance. The audio buffer is having seconds of delay.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for since? Currently facing the same issue